# QSortFilterProxyModel and filter by integers, booleans

Tags: qt, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a `QSortFilterProxyModel` which is connected to a `QSqlQueryModel`. In the underlying query there are boolean and integer fields. I would like to filter by these boolean, integers, etc. values. Surprisingly enough (or maybe I'm wrong) `QSortFilterProxyModel` only filters by strings. This is for instance a "problem" if you want to filter IDs (which are normally integers). If you try for instance to filter an `ID=22`, you get all the IDs with "22" inside (122, 222, 322, etc.). See [this link](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/5046) for a non very elegant solution.

But how would you filter by boolean fields? Can someone give some hint? I suppose I have to subclass `QSortFilterProxyModel`, or is there another method?

Answer (score 6):

A bit late, but it could be useful to others (and maybe some true expert might add precision/corrections) !

A **QSortFilterProxyModel** instance uses the method

```
bool QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex & source_parent)
```

to determine if the given row should be kept or not. 
By default it will simply test that the string returned by

```
myProxyModel.data(source_row, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
```

matches the regular expression you might have set earlier using

```
myProxyModel.setFilterRegExp(myRegex)
```

Since you are **subclassing** this **QSortFilterProxyModel** you can easily define a new way to filter your items.

Add a method to set the ID you want to check

```
myProxyModel.setFilterID(myRefId)
```

then override the **filterAcceptsRow** to do the test against the ID instead of the regular expression !

You could also want to keep both method (or more) available. To do so, in your **filterAcceptsRow**  method read the data from

```
myProxyModel.data(source_row, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
```

instead of **DisplayRole**. When setting the **UserRole** you can store any data, not just string.
Here is an exemple (in python, it's shorter to write, but it works the same in any language) where we store a custom proxy object into the model:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class MyDummyObj(object):

    def __init__(self, objLabel, objID, hidden=False)
        self.__label = objLabel
        self.__id = objLabel
        self.__hidden = hidden

    def getLabel(self):
        return self.__label

    def getID(self):
        return self.__id

    def isSecret(self):
        return self.__hidden


class MyProxyModel(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyProxyModel, self).__init__()
        self.__testID = None
        self.__showHidden = False

    def setFilterID(self, filterID):
        self.__testID = filterID

    def showHiddenRows(self, showHidden=False)
        self.__showHidden = showHidden

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):
        model = self.sourceModel()
        myObject = model.data(model.index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent),
                              QtCore.Qt.UserRole).toPyObject()

        if not self.__showHidden:
            if myObject.isSecret():
                return False

        if self.__testID is not None:
            return self.__testID == myObject.getID()

        return self.getFilterRegExp().exactMatch(myObject.getLabel())
```

Comment: seems to be the advocated solution proposed by the experts : https://forum.qt.io/topic/6102/qsortfilterproxymodel-filter-by-ids-solved

Answer (score 1):

You can quite explicitly filter boolean roles with [setFilterFixedString](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#setFilterFixedString): `filterModel->setFilterFixedString("false")`
or `filterModel->setFilterFixedString("true")` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution is to use regexp with start and end anchor :

```
 proxyModel->setFilterRegExp(QString("^%1$").arg(id));
```